# Cannot start Website in IIS - W3SVC running

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to start a Website in IIS, but it doesn't start and gives me following error:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) is stopped. Websites
> cannot be started unless the World Wide Web Publishing Service is
> running.

How can I resolve? I don't even know how to start W3SVC. Need help

Comment: Start World Wide Web Publishing Service https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250472(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: Open up services.msc, right click and start "World Wide Web Publishing Service"

Answer (score 89, accepted):

First verify that the World Wide Web Publishing Service is installed and not disabled. [Source:[MSDN]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997600%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

> Right-click My Computer on the desktop, and then click Manage.
>
> Expand the Services and Applications node, and then click the Services
>   node.
>
> In the right pane, locate the World Wide Web Publishing Service.
>
> If the World Wide Web Publishing Service is not displayed in the list
>   of services installed, follow the steps in the procedure below to
>   install it.
>
> If the World Wide Web Publishing Service is displayed but has a status
>   other than Started, continue with the steps below to start it.
>
> Right-click World Wide Web Publishing Service, and then click
>   Properties.
>
> Verify the Startup Type is Automatic and the Service status is set to
>   Started.
>
> Click Apply, and then click OK.

To install the World Wide Web Publishing Service

> On the Start menu, select Settings, Control Panel, and then click Add
>   or Remove Programs
>
> Click Add/Remove Windows Components.
>
> In the Components list, select the Application Server check box, and
>   then click Details.
>
> Select Internet Information Services Manager, and then click Details.
>
> Select World Wide Web Service, and then select the check box.
>
> Click OK two times to return to the Components list, and then click
>   Next.
>
> Click Finish when the IIS service is installed.

Answer (score 51):

Here are the quicker steps for restarting W3SVC:

1. Right click on the bar on the bottom of the screen, observe a menu pops up, then choose *Task Manager*
2. Choose tab *Services*
3. Find the `W3SVC` service under `Name`
4. Right click that service and choose *start*

Comment: https://medium.com/@chongfai13/solved-iis-website-cannot-be-started-unless-both-the-windows-activation-service-was-and-the-7bd6b27b5f30

Comment: i have no idea why this service stopped all of a sudden but that did the trick

Comment: On recent versions of Windows Server 2016 and above for Data Center the label may be "World Wide Web Publishing Service" instead of "W3SVC"

Answer (score 12):

For me the World Wide Web Publishing Service(W3SVC) was stuck in "stopping" state, so I was unable to start the IIS or the service manually.

What I did was to kill the service from administrative command prompt using below command and then I was able to start the IIS

```
Taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq W3SVC"
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue will happen, only when the **world wide web publishing service** is stopped.
Please go to services.msc
look for  [world wide web publishing service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH7aX.png)

Select the service and click start, once the status of this service is changed to running, all your sites in IIS which were stopped, they will be started automatically.

if not, you will able to start them.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue yesterday, finally, the fix is simple in our case, go to registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WAS\Parameters`, we found there was an item named `GenerateKeys` which is not on other servers, so we deleted the `GenerateKeys` item and it is working.

Comment: Tried everything before finding this! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

in windows server 2016

click windows button

type services and open it

choose "World Wide Web Publishing Service"

right click and start

good luck

Answer (score 1):

If your control panel **does not have "Add or Remove Programs"** to install the ***World Wide Web Publishing Service***.

Steps:

1. Click Start Menu
2. Search for *Programs*(or *Programs and features*)
3. Turn Windows features on or off
4. Enable **Internet Information Services** (check all subitems) and **Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core**

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Search for "Server Manager" inside "Search Windows" and open server manager. Select IIS from the tree menu on the left. Look for "Services" section in IIS menu. The general IIS services are listed here. Select "World Wide Web Publishing Service(W3SVC)" and right click on the service and select "Stat Service". This should solve the problem.